# How do I access a TableViewController in app delegate?

Tags: objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller, appdelegate

Currently, I have a SplitViewController setup. Wherein the MasterViewController has a bar button, when pressed, a UITableViewController popovers.

**I'm want to connect the delegate in UITableViewController to MasterViewController.** Based on tutorials, most people do this in app delegate.

Here's my code in app delegate. I haven't added the TableViewController class yet.

```
UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *) self.window.rootViewController; 

splitViewController.delegate = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];

DetailViewController *detailViewController =(DetailViewController *) [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];

MasterViewController *masterViewController = (MasterViewController *) [[splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] topViewController];

masterViewController.delegate = detailViewController; 
detailViewController.delegate = masterViewController;
```

Comment: And now you want to keep a reference from the app delegate to the MasterViewController?

Comment: Hi! Yes, I want to do that.

Comment: Well, then, instead of dynamically defining masterviewcontroller within that method why don't you define it as iVar in your application delegate subclass and keep a reference to the controller?